# Amazon aws ec2 login via putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian, putty

I had successfully used putty to login into `Debian-8.1` on AWS by using key file. Once I upgraded debian using the command `apt-get upgrade` and tried to login through putty, it shows the error which i mentioned below:

> putty fatal error: network connection refused

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Do you think `apt-get upgrade` upgraded the SSH package on the machine?

Comment: i am not so good in that and so cannot say about that. But after the upgaradation i am not getting connected via putty.

Answer (score 0):

I think Kernal Upgrade , Reboots the system in Linux and if you have not allocated Elastic Ip to the instance , the Ip would have have changed.

Did you Check the Instance IP ? Are you able to Login via Web based Interface from EC2- Console ?

Comment: i can login to aws console via web based interface and there it showing the instance is running.

Comment: You wont change it will automatically if instace was rebooted , can you connect via web console ?

Comment: ya i login into web console and when i checked the system log i found that the ssh server is starting and stopping. So i think ssh server is not working. how can i resolve it?

Comment: Reboots don't change the IP, only shutdown followed by restart.

Comment: Extremely Sorry I meant Restart.

Comment: GO CHECK the the instance Public IP and connect using the public DNS name as advice.  It won't bite you .

Comment: ya the public dns is same as before and i tried with that too but still showin g the same error. How can i fix ssh crash issue from the instane if its so?